# ¿Cómo comparo doubles en java?

Tags: java

Para saber si son iguales ocupo:

```
Math.abs(variable1-variable2)<0.0000001
```

> Cómo se hace cuando quiero saber si es menor o mayor?

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0):

Para saber si una variable de un tipo de dato primitivo (por ejemplo short, int, long, float, double) es mayor, menor o igual a otra variable simplemente puedes utilizar operadores relacionales, los cuales sirven para realizar   comparaciones   de  igualdad, desigualdad  y   relación    de  menor   o   mayor.  El  resultado   de  estos   operadores  es  siempre un  valor   boolean (true   o false)    según   se  cumpla  o   no  la  relación    considerada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso, para saber que variable almacena el valor mayor, el código que hace la comparación sería:

```
if(variable1 > variable2){ // revisa si el valor de la variable 1 es más grande
     // aquí pondría el código que se ejecuta si variable1 es más grande
}else{
     if(variable1 < variable2){ // revisa si el valor de la variable 1 es menor
          // aquí pondría el código que se ejecuta si variable2 es más grande
     }else{ // si los valores son iguales
          //aquí pondría el código que se ejecuta si las dos variables tienen el mismo valor
     }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

La propia clase **java.lang.Double** implementa un método **compare()**, que recibe dos parámetros de tipo Double y devuelve un **0** si son iguales, **< 0** si el primer parámetro es menor que el segundo y **> 0** si el primer parámetro es mayor que el segundo.

Por ejemplo:

```
    if (Double.compare(param1, param2) == 0) { 
        System.out.println("Iguales"); 
    } 
    else if (Double.compare(param1, param2) < 0) { 
        System.out.println("param1 < param2"); 
    } 
    else { 
        System.out.println("param1 > param2"); 
    }
```